# How to combining bassistance.de jquery validator with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form that I would like to validate client side and then post through ajax.
I have the form working using one or the other but am not sure how to combine them. Having visited bassistance ajax pages I am left more confused than before.

Client side:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#this_form").validate({
    });
});
```

Ajax:

```
jQuery("#submit").click(function(){

    var formData = jQuery("#this_form").serializeArray();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_form.php",
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });

    return false;
});
```

What I would like to know is how I can trigger the ajax on successful validation combining the two methods above. I am asking on the assumption that there is a straight forward way of doing so as all the tuts I find bear little resemblance to the above code.

Have tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit').live('click', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#this_form');
    if(form.valid()){
        var formData = jQuery("#this_form").serializeArray();
             jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process_form.php",
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
                    });
               return false;
               };
   });
});
```

But this doesn't validate the required field and just does the ajax.
I guess what I am looking for is a way of the validator returning true without submitting the form and then firing off the ajax event but I don't know how to construct this.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#this_form").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form){
   jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "process_form.php",
   cache: false,
   data: formData,
   success: onSuccess,
   error: onError
   });
  }
 });
});

Comment: Not allowed to answer own question but I sorted as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   if($("#form").valid()){
      //Ajax submission
    }
});
```

And in your button you can add a `type="button"` to prevent the automatic submission.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted with this:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
  jQuery("#this_form").validate({
        debug: true,    
        rules:{
                    // add rules here
        },
        messages: {
            //add messages here
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processform.php",
                cache: false,
                data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError,
            });
        }           
  });
});

function onSuccess(data, status)
{
data = jQuery.trim(data);
jQuery("#return_message").html(data);
}

function onError(data, status)
{
// handle an error
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow makes it very hard to participate, original account locked, but not informed of any reason unable to vote on Jorge's helpful response, unable to post the answer for other users, unable to login to prevent further notifications being sent or to close the account, very bizarre, frustrating and also completely pointless because if I were anything other than a nice bloke ,albeit a little busy, and I wanted to do something malicious I could can create another user account very easily and cause mayhem.

Comment: Obviously as a result I will be unable to flag the question as answered or say thanks to Jorge for his contribution which works fine but does not allow the fallback I need on this occasion if JS is disabled.